# Lsmeans library error installing estimability

Tags: lsmeans

I am trying to load the lsmeans library.

Get this message:

> library(lsmeans) # for lsmeans
>   Loading required package: estimability

I then installed

> install.packages("estimability")

but even after done, when I run this library I get the same message.

> library(lsmeans) # for lsmeans
>   Loading required package: estimability

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just now saw this question. The **lsmeans** package depends on the **estimability** package. So when you load **lsmeans**, you get a message that it is also loading **estimability**. It is not an error.